# Python 3.4/PyQt5 Cannot import QtCore

Tags: python, import, pyqt5

I'm trying to run an example script using PyQt 5 that contains the following:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

This throws:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'
```

I'm running 64-bit versions of both Python 3.4 and PyQt 5 on 64-bit Windows 10. When I try

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

in the terminal it works fine; I only get the import error when running a script. Other similar questions on StackOverflow led me to check sys.path, which produced:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5']
```

os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)
results in a long list of directories, including the location of PyQt5 in the Python34 folder.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Python and PyQt, and tried PyQt4 instead of 5, all with no success.

Comment: I'm just typing 'python tax_calc.py' in the command line.

Comment: Are you opening the Python terminal with the same command?

Comment: I wasn't before, but I just tried it that way now and it still has the same result.

Comment: You cannot have difference in the imports if you run `python` interactive terminal and `python script.py` command. If this is the case please edit the question and paste the full command and output of both commands, because now there is something missing from the question which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you tried using the [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)? That is: `py -3 tax_calc.py`.